# How to translate html tags inside Angular Mat card content

Tags: angular, mat-card

I have to display contents of a json file. The contents contain html tags. the real code is a little complex, but similar to this example (so can't use inner html etc)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4iwdag-1nm3tc?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.html

I would like formatted display. Is it possible?

Comment: pretty straight forward, make a dictionary of all 'custom' html elements, and replace them with standard ones, then bind it to innerHTML

Comment: I'm not sure your suggestion works, as already there was <p> getting displayed  as <p>, not treated like paragraph